# How do I remove linux-kernel-image 4.0.2 and install 3.*.* back?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I am not sure if kernel 4.0.3 started  giving every time some errors but since I installed kernel 4.0.2, it shows many errors.

How can I remove the recent kernel image and install the previous 3.*.* one?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? And how did you install that kernel?

Comment: I did it referring to some blogs. Which mentioned how to first download and then to insrall the downloaded file. Its Ubuntu14.04LTS

Comment: I made an answer. If anything is not clear, comment.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE:  This works for Ubuntu 14.04.2**

To install the 3.16 kernel, type in the following in a terminal window:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic`

after it is installed reboot your host to the 3.16.xxx kernel. Then from a terminal window type in:

`sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.0* linux-image-4.0*`

to remove the Linux 4.0.x kernels.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot with a previous 3.x.x kernel using grub menu.

   Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting, and you will see that menu.
2. Install and run Synaptic.
3. Remove  4.0.2 linux-headers and linux-image.

Comment: No.1 How to boot from grub menu would you please elaborate.

Comment: Explained it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly you shouldn't have a Linux kernel that begins with 4 on 14.04 Trusty Tahr. The 14.04 Lts starts at kernel version 3.13.24, 14.10 Utopic currently is using a 3.16.. kernel version, and VividVervet is using 3.19..; whats really interesting is that you can figure out how to install a kernel, but you cant remove one! (jk just playing)

To remove that kernel, if indeed it is listed, or its repository is listed
in one of these places:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/

/var/lib/dpkg/info

/etc/apt/sources.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

than running a apt-get --purge remove e.g.

```
:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove  linux-image-extra-4.02.x-xx-generic 

:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-headers-4.02.x-xx-generic

:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove -y && sudo reboot
```

will remove the unwanted linux-image and linux-headers. By deduction it is assumed since you dont know how to remove your current active kernel, you didnt remove the previous one, therefore removing the current kernel using the package management system should automatically reinstall your previous kernel unless you cleaned out all your packages from:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Also by running the ls -a command on the file-system's root /

```
:~$ ls -a /
```

you should be able to see a vmlinuz (your current vm image) and vmlinuz.old (the previous non active vm), if you do not see a vmlinuz.old[image: Vmlinuz.old] you need to download a previous image and a set of previous headers. You can choose one by running a apt-cache search on linux-image, for example:

```
:~$ apt-cache search linux image
```

Once performed the necessary reboot (the old image will not take affect until after a reboot) run the uname -a command to verify everything has worked out:

```
:~$ uname -a
```

this should display something like the following:

```
Linux geo-Inspiron-3520 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Why purge only linux-image-extra, and leave linux-image? It will not remove kernel, but makes system unusable. Almost everything wlse is wrong too.

Comment: Sir you're incorrect

Comment: Can I have back my point now?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Photo catalog of the process took about 6 minutes totally while cooking dinner.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Reinstalling the previously removed kernel:

[image]

[image]
With 4.02 kernel and removing it

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]